# The required column 'id' was not present in the results of a `FromSql` operation in EFcore

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a major problem with `FromSql` and that's it :

I have a model like this:

```
public partial class  model
{
    public string name
}
```

I want to get some result from my procedure in database(sql serever).
when I execute below code

```
var sql = "EXECUTE [myprocedure] @param1 ";
SqlParameter sqlParameter = new SqlParameter
{
     ParameterName = "param1",
     DbType = DbType.Int32,
     Value = 10;
}
var result = db.model.FromSql(sql,SqlParameter);
```

it show an exeption like this:
`The entity type 'model' requires a primary key to be defined.`
So I add primary key to my model:

```
public partial class  model
{
    [key]
    public int ID {set;get;}

    public string name
}
```

But in this time it shows this execption :`The required column 'ID' was not present in the results of a 'FromSql' operation.`

I know I must add `ID` to my Database response but I can't do this beacuse I have a lot of procedure in my Database so I can't edit all of them.
So I am looking for a method to solve my problem without editing my procedures.

Can some help me?!

Comment: i would save that fromsql into a var and check in runtime what is it returning perhaps its case sensitive and ID is really Id for example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using Entity Framework Core 2.x take a look at Query Types (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/query-types). 
Tables (entity types) always need an ID, query types do not.

With query types you can omit the ID. Otherwise you have to make sure that your stored procedure also returns an ID since table/entity  types always need one.

Starting with EF Core 3.0 there is a .HasNoKey() instead of query types to define entities without ID (https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#query-types-are-consolidated-with-entity-types).

Comment: Thanks for response @ctron ,You say I use `ExecuteSqlCommand` instead of `FromSql` . if yes : i need some resut from my procedure so I can not use `ExecuteSqlCommand`, if no :Can you describe more and make an example?

Comment: Do you use EF6 or EF Core? If you use EF Core as the "entity-framework-core" tag in the question suggests, query types are the solution. For EF6 I don't think there is such a thing (but maybe there is an EF6 expert who knows a solution). Maybe a framework like Dapper would be an alternative for calling stored procedures. Entity Framework has its strengths more in change tracking and working with tables.

Comment: I test it and it work. but I use EF Core 3, and it shows a warning that `DbQuery() is obsoleted. use DBSet<T> instead` !! what to do I do?!

Comment: @amir133 Using unreleased (preview) software is your right, but so are the risks. You can't expect us to solve problems in such software. Until it gets released, all issues should go to their GitHub issue tracker.

Comment: I don't have any experience with the changes in version 3.0 yet. A good starting point might be https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#query-types-are-consolidated-with-entity-types

It seems that there is now a .HasNoKey() for entities.

Comment: I found my answer in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#query-types-are-consolidated-with-entity-types and my problem solved . So @ctron please complete your answer and take some example to mark your answer.

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server, one thing to check is that your query is returning columns matching your object for binding.

If you have the below object which is a `DBSet<T>` and is to be binded with the incoming SQL call.

```
public class Object 
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Make sure SQL is returning a column of type integer name 'Id'

```
SELECT @Id as 'Id'
```

If you are returning the actual columns themselves such as

```
SELECT Id from User
```

then you do not need to worry.

Run your query/stored procedure and see if any of the columns are (No Column Name)

[image]